# Is it possible for a pure reactive load (Z= jX) to be adapted to a line with characteristic impedance of 75 Ω? (RF circuit)

Tags: rf

I think the answer is yes.

For example, a shunt inductor with a series capacitor in (2) :

[image]

would drive the load impedance that is located at the extreme circunference where the reflective coefficient is equal to one to the center of the smith chart.

Comment: No, not possible. Think about it: a pure inductance cannot absorb any energy, so anything you launch down the line toward it is going to come back at you, no matter what kind of non-dissipative network you put in front of it.

Comment: So no matter what components i put there will be always a reflective wave? How so?

Comment: Because there's no place for the energy to go.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Asked exactly as stated - no.

But no real L and C have infinite quality factor, there is always radiative losses, and many other. All of this together will help you determine equivalent resistor. All of the losses can be simplified to one resistor, for most purposes anyway, two resistors if you are doing some more realistic simulations.

Have no idea about it? Make it so that quality factor is 100. Unless you are doing something too good or too bad, it wont be far off.

And then, once you have it, yes. You can do impedance matching against this network.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is it possible for a pure reactive load (Z= jX) to be adapted to a
> line with characteristic impedance of 75 Ω? (RF circuit)*

1. If you add a parallel capacitor of Z = -jX, this tunes the loading impedance to a high value of resistance (usually kΩ to tens of kΩ). Then you can fairly accurately terminate with your cable's characteristic impedance in parallel with the jx and -jx pair
2. Alternatively, you can series tune and put the cable termination resistor in series with jx and -jx. Series tuning creates a short circuit at the required operating frequency and therefore adding 75 Ω correctly terminates the cable.